# Find the closest number in one dataframe with another dataframe and split them into sub dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, intervals

I have 2 data frames one containing the timeseries data of df1 and another timeseries data of df2. What I am trying to do is that for every value in df1 I need to figure out the closest value in df2 and divide df2 into sub data frames depending upon the time series values. I would appreciate your help in this

I tried using for loop to integrate the lengths but the problem is that I am not arriving at the solution

Comment: Hello Padma and welcome ! Could you share with us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g the first lines of each of your dataframe, as well as what the expected result would look like ?